# Migrated from Server 2003 to 2008, ODBC problems

Tags: asp-classic, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008

I migrated a website written in classic asp to windows server 2008 RS/ IIS 7.5. I made all the changes to run classic asp on the server and everything works fine with *.asp pages, except when it pertains to *.asp pages trying to access an *.mdb file.

**The error I am receiving:**

Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80004005'

[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

/MyChildFolder/Default.asp, line 9

As I said, this code worked fine just moments ago on a Windows 2003 Server/ IIS 6.0.

Comment: can you add your connection string to the post, and do you have the right ODBC driver installed (x86/x64 bit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very simple to solve this:

1. Open IIS Manager, I assume 7.5
2. Open the Application Pool node and click on the domain name in question.
3. Choose Advanced settings on the right side.
4. In the Genl section, 2nd down, "Enable 32 bit applications", set that to true.

You should be good to go.

Comment: @JoeGrasso i strongly suggest you to Upgrade your Current ODBC driver to the 64-bit version ASAP and return your production environment to 64-bit native.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 2008 has 64bit ODBC that doesn't work with ASP as ASP uses 32bit or you should set this up to.

You can access 32 ODBC here
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe

Comment: windows 8? he's moved to server 2008, not windows 8

Comment: typo.. Cant stand windows 8! Wouldn't recommend installing that as a server!